# Find gaps between pandas dateranges that overlap

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I'm trying to find the gaps where a set of dateranges don't overlap a larger daterange. In the below example I'd like to find each gap where `daterange_1` to `daterange_3` don't overlap `big_daterange`.

At the moment I've gotten this far, but I'm stuck in extracting the gaps from `diff`, if that is even the best way to go about this.

```py
import pandas as pd

daterange_1 = pd.date_range("2009-01-01", "2010-01-01")
daterange_2 = pd.date_range("2012-01-01", "2014-01-01")
daterange_3 = pd.date_range("2016-01-01", "2019-01-01")

big_daterange = pd.date_range("2001-01-01", "2021-01-01")

combined = daterange_1.union(daterange_2).union(daterange_3)

# Get the dates in big_daterange that aren't in combined
diff = big_daterange.difference(combined)
```

What I'm most interested in is how to extract the gaps (where a gap is a daterange of contiguous datetimes) and create a list of them like this:

```
gaps = [gap_daterange_1, gap_daterange_2, ...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
s = diff.to_series()
grp = s.diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(days=1)).cumsum()
gaps = s.groupby(grp).agg(['min','max'])
gaps
```

Output:

```
         min        max
1 2001-01-01 2008-12-31
2 2010-01-02 2011-12-31
3 2014-01-02 2015-12-31
4 2019-01-02 2021-01-01
```

Details:

First, convert the DateTimeIndex to a pd.Series, using `to_series`.
Next use `diff` to find the difference between two consective values.
If diff is greater than one day, then mark this record as True.  Use `cumsum` to create groups of records between True records.  Lastly, `groupby` grp an use max and min to find the start and end of each group.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks, could you add a few comments to explain what's going on?

Comment: @oxidising Done.  See details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reindex` method.
Everywhere you find NaT, it's because the date is missing in dtiX:

```py
dti1 = pd.date_range("2009-01-01", "2010-01-01")
dti2 = pd.date_range("2012-01-01", "2014-01-01")
dti3 = pd.date_range("2016-01-01", "2019-01-01")

dti = pd.date_range("2001-01-01", "2021-01-01")

sr = pd.concat([dti1.to_series(), dti2.to_series(), dti3.to_series()]) \
       .sort_index().reindex(dti)

sr = sr[sr.isnull()]
```

```py
>>> sr.index
DatetimeIndex(['2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-04',
               '2001-01-05', '2001-01-06', '2001-01-07', '2001-01-08',
               '2001-01-09', '2001-01-10',
               ...
               '2020-12-23', '2020-12-24', '2020-12-25', '2020-12-26',
               '2020-12-27', '2020-12-28', '2020-12-29', '2020-12-30',
               '2020-12-31', '2021-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=5111, freq=None)
```

Find gaps by creating groups of non-consecutive days:

```py
sr = sr.index.to_series()
groups = sr.sub(sr.shift()) \
           .fillna(pd.Timedelta(days=1)) \
           .ne(pd.Timedelta(days=1)) \
           .cumsum()
gaps = sr.groupby(groups).agg(['min','max'])
```

```py
>>> gaps
         min        max
0 2001-01-01 2008-12-31
1 2010-01-02 2011-12-31
2 2014-01-02 2015-12-31
3 2019-01-02 2021-01-01
```

Comment: Can you show me how to extract the gaps from the difference between the dateranges? Otherwise this doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Changing `sr1` to `sr` in your grouping code, this now outputs what I was after, thanks.